# Difference between time period formulas? Continuous time vs discrete time?

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis, periodic

For calculating period of continuous time signal,we simply divide 2pi by omega and get period value

But in case of discrete time signal, procedure is not straight forward like continuous time, although same formula (2pi divide by omega) is used but there are some other conditions, what are they? And if we get any fraction in answer,we choose denominator as period (what is reason for this??)

Please explain calculation of discrete time period with example

Update: After reading the comments , i meant strictly periodic signal and i am looking for example related to sinusoids

Comment: Do you mean strictly periodic signals, i.e. a signal where $x_k = x_{k - K}$ for all $k$?  Or do you mean a quasi-periodic signal, i.e. a signal where $x_k = \sin 2 \pi f k$, where $f$ is not a rational number?

Comment: I meant strictly periodic

Comment: If possible, please also explain the scenario of quasi periodic,

Comment: Please _edit your question_ to reflect any refinements rather than leaving them in the comments.  While you're doing that, please post an example of what you mean by your comment "2pi divide by omega" -- I assume you mean that your periodic signal happens to be sinusoidal.  Please supply the math, then the question will be much clearer.